# Parse multi-format string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse:

> "-key -key-name-pair key=value key="the values" key='the value' key my-key-gh=the-values my-key-gh="the no-values""

I would like the following strings in return

1. -key
2. -key-name-pair
3. key=value
4. key="the values"
5. key='the value'
6. key
7. my-key-gh=the-values
8. my-key-gh="the no-values"

I've tried this regular expression:

```
(-([a-z])+)? |((\w)+=(\w)+)|((\w)+="(.*)")|((\w)+='(.*?)')|(\w+-\w+)+
```

What's wrong with my expression?

Comment: Why does splitting by spaces does not work?

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'-?\w[\w-]*(?:=(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^\s"']+))?', text)`

Comment: @Daniel Cause of the parts in quotes

Comment: `shlex.split` gets pretty close

Comment: You need to make a [mre] including a specific problem and runnable code.

Comment: On second thought maybe you don't *need* to make a MRE, but it would help a lot.

Comment: Perfect ! @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'''-?\w[\w-]*(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^\s"']+))?''', text)
```

With escaped quotes support:

```
re.findall(r'''-?\w[\w-]*(?:=(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|[^\s"']+))?''', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CeIZHG/1)

**Details**

- `-?` - an optional hyphen
- `\w[\w-]*` - a word char followed with 0+ word or hyphen chars
- `(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^\s"']+))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `=` - an equal sign
  - `(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^\s"']+)` - either of

    - `"[^"]*"` - string between double quotes having no double quotes inside
    - `'[^']*'` - string between single quotes having no single quotes inside
    - `[^\s"']+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace, `"` and `'`.

Comment: could you update this to support: key.name=value ? so the full string would look like "-key -key-name-pair key=value key="the values" key='the value' key my-key-gh=the-values my-key-gh="the no-values" key.name=value"

Comment: @LDM Add `.` to the `[\w-]` character class, use `-?\w[\w.-]*(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^\s"']+))?`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/CeIZHG/2).